# @ngrx/store computedStates[currentStateIndex] is undefined

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am currently learning about `@ngrx/store` and I am running into a strange situation that I need some help on.

I have created a simple store, with an inital value. I installed the Redux Devtools and that shows me the initialState:

```
{
  app: {
    products: {
      data: [
        {
        ...
        }
      ],
      loaded: false,
      loading: false
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I try to `console.log` that state I get this error:

> TypeError: computedStates[currentStateIndex] is undefined

This is my code for logging the state:

```
  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.store.select<any>('app').subscribe(state => console.log(state));
  }
```

Any pointers in the direction where I should be looking are welcome.

**Update**
When I disable the StoreDevtoolsModule in my Module imports, the error disappears. This line:

```
StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument()
```

However, off course now the Redux Devtools don't work anymore! So, how can I get the application and the Devtools working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into an issue with Angular 5 and the Redux Devtools. It is currently under investigation here:

https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/624

The only confirmed workaround at the moment is downgrading to Angular 4.